# Check if user input is part of the NeutralCultures list

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox, culture

I want to check if the user input is part of the NeutralCultures List. So that is not possible to input a value which is not in the list.

```
Dim Culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo
For Each Culture In System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(Globalization.CultureTypes.NeutralCultures)
         cLanguage.ap_ComboAdd(Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName & "|" & Culture.DisplayName)
Next
```

The input of the user is saved in .language = cLanguage.Text - how can I now check if cLanguage.Text is part of the list?

Thank all for your help

Comment: Why not just make them make a selection from a ComboBox that your fill with the available choices?

Answer (score 0):

I made a List(Of T) and used it as a DataSource of a ComboBox. I also used the .Contains method of the list to see if user input is in the list. I think it is a lot to ask a user to enter an exact match. I would much prefer the user choosing from the ComboBox.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim cLanguage As New List(Of String)
    Dim Culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo
    For Each Culture In System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(Globalization.CultureTypes.NeutralCultures)
        cLanguage.Add(Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName & "|" & Culture.DisplayName)
    Next
    ComboBox1.DataSource = cLanguage
    If cLanguage.Contains(LanguageTextBox.Text) Then
        'Do something
    End If
End Sub
```